# Unable to configure SSH in Cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I'm new to Cygwin and I'm trying to install Cygwin with SSH. But currently I got a problem while configuring SSH. 
I passed all steps for configuring SSH until it asks for the password of the privileged user "cyg_server". I was unable to type any character into the Cygwin for the password. I don't know how to provide the password for this privileged user.

Can you please help me on this? Or can you please show me some other way to install the SSH using Cygwin? I appreciate all helps.

Regards,

Sam Vo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike most Windows programs, OpenSSH does not show asterisks when you type in a password, as is customary with software written for Unix-like operating systems. Don't worry – OpenSSH is still accepting the password.

Once you enter a password for the `cyg_server` account (the main requirements are that it must not be blank and that it must meet any password strength policy enforced by Windows) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the `ssh-host-config` process can continue.

Comment: Thank you for answer me. I successfully installed SSH. However, I cannot start the SSHD Service. I got the following error:

================================================================
$ net start sshd
The CYGWIN sshd service is starting.
The CYGWIN sshd service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534.
===========================================================

Could you please look into this and help me start the SSHD Service?

Answer (score 1):

Like on the most OS similar to Linux, your are for security-reasons not able to see signs(e.g. *) for the typed letters.

Simply type in your password and press enter, this should working!